# Undefined variable AMP and laravel

Tags: laravel, amp-html

How can I render errors/success messages I got from the server with laravel and AMP here is an example but it doesn't work I get undefined variable

**server side (laravel)**

```
public function userAjaxHasNotLogedIn()
{
    return response()->json(['loged' => false], 400)
                     ->header('AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin',"http://localhost:8000");
}
```

the function is working fine and it return a json file with the variable loged

**client side (AMP)**

```
<div submit-error>
  <template type="amp-mustache">
    <a style="cursor: pointer;" id="submitloginbtn" on="tap:loginform.show,submitloginbtn.hide" > Réessayer </a>
  </template>
</div><div submit-success>
<template type="amp-mustache">Vous êtes connecté {{ loged }}</template></div>
```

the error Use of undefined constant loged - assumed 'loged'

Comment: It will be better if you add a json data with your query.

Comment: I didn't understand, can you please explaine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to use blade syntax with javaScript. you can do like this. use `@` with blade `@{{logged}}`

```
<div submit-error>
<template type="amp-mustache">
<a style="cursor: pointer;" id="submitloginbtn" on="tap:loginform.show,submitloginbtn.hide" > Réessayer </a>
```

Vous êtes connecté @{{ loged }}

Comment: can you please tell me where I can find it in the doc